# Code coverage updated only when 'Run all'

Tags: code-coverage

I made a change to the code and When i try to do a code coverage via

*Test > New run > Selected the test class > selected the method > Run*

the code coverage is seen as 0% BUT when i do a "run all" the code coverage is updated to 100%. Why such a behavior? any inputs on this please?

Comment: r u running test class from dev console?

Comment: yes from dev console

Comment: run your test class from UI. setup-->Build-->Develop-->Apex Test Execution. try to run your test class here and check

Comment: got a pointer here "https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoyAAE"

Comment: yeah this a issue in winter 16 release..

Comment: Hi rata,  by running thru "setup-->Build-->Develop-->Apex Test Execution." how can i view the % coverage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31764/discussion-between-ratan-and-prabhu-sethupathy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to execute run from dev console this issue

Issue link https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoyAAE
(Note: If you are affected with issue please vote  success community)

if you try to run from UI then properly test code updates.

This issue  in Winter '16 orgs.

Hope salesforce will fix this issue soon.